# Autofac's Contextual binding not working in ASP.Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, autofac, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Recently I had to take advantage of the contextual binding that Autofac supports but somehow in ASP.NET Core 2.0 it's just not working. I followed the example (options 2 and 3) on the [How do I pick a service implementation by context?](http://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/select-by-context.html) FAQ page, however I managed to make it work only in ASP.NET MVC 5 and ASP.NET WEB API 2 projects.
Example:

```
public interface ISender
{
  void Send(Destination dest, Content content);
}

// We can implement the interface for different
// "sending strategies":
public class PostalServiceSender : ISender { ... }
public class EmailNotifier : ISender { ... }

public class ShippingProcessor
{
  public ShippingProcessor(ISender shippingStrategy) { ... }
}

public class CustomerNotifier
{
  public CustomerNotifier(ISender notificationStrategy) { ... }
}
```

The following binding configuration **failed** to work:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<PostalServiceSender>()
       .As<ISender>()
       .AsSelf();
builder.RegisterType<EmailNotifier>()
       .As<ISender>()
       .AsSelf()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<DefaultSender>()
           .As<ISender>()
           .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.RegisterType<ShippingController>()
       .WithParameter(
         new ResolvedParameter(
           (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ISender),
           (pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<PostalServiceSender>()))
           .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<CustomersController>();
       .WithParameter(
         new ResolvedParameter(
           (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ISender),
           (pi, ctx) => ctx.Resolve<EmailNotifier>()))
           .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
var container = builder.Build();
```

What is expected from the above binding configurations is the DefaultSender class to be the the default implementation of ISender. Only **PostalServiceSender** and **CustomerNotifier** are configured to receive a different implementation of ISender.
Unfortunately the DefaultSender implementation is passed anywhere ISender is requested.
Has anyone experienced such behavior in .NET Core 2.0?

Comment: do you mean that `ShippingController` is receiving a `DefaultSender` instead of the expected `PostalServiceSender` ? could you share the constructor of this controller ?

Comment: Nevermind. it may also be related to this : http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration is great and everything should work fine but for ASP.net core controller.

Controllers in ASP.net core are not created by `Autofac` but byb ASP.net core :

> By default, ASP.NET Core will resolve the controller parameters from the container but doesn’t actually resolve the controller from the container. This usually isn’t an issue but it does mean:
>
> the lifecycle of the controller is handled by the framework, not the request lifetime.
>
> The lifecycle of controller constructor parameters is handled by the request lifetime.
>
> Special wiring that you may have done during registration of the controller (like setting up property injection) won’t work.
>   
>   
> You can change this by specifying `AddControllersAsServices()` when you register MVC with the service collection. Doing that will automatically register controller types into the `IServiceCollection` when you call `builder.Populate(services)`.
>   
>   >> http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services

All you have to do is to call `AddControllersAsServices`

```
// Add controllers as services so they'll be resolved.
services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices();
```

BTW even if your code works, it is not the best practice to register the same service multiple time and rely on default order.

```
builder.RegisterType<PostalServiceSender>()
       .Keyed<ISender>("postal");
builder.RegisterType<EmailNotifier>()
       .Keyed<ISender>("email")
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<DefaultSender>()
       .As<ISender>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

and your controller like this :

```
builder.RegisterType<ShippingController>()
       .WithParameter(
         new ResolvedParameter(
           (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ISender),
           (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<ISender>("postal")))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<CustomersController>()
       .WithParameter(
         new ResolvedParameter(
           (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(ISender),
           (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<ISender>("email")))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: Thanks mate, indeed AddControllersAsServices() solved my problem. We are migrating from ASP.NET MVC5 and Ninject to ASP.NET Core 2.0 and Autofac and I guess we're still learning.
I agree with you that's not a good idea to rely on configuration order but used to that functionality with Ninject, where actually order of binding registrations does not matter in this case.
P.S. I voted for your answer but, I still don't have the required points.